# Calculating a distance matrix and placing within a cell of a grouped data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, distance-matrix

So, basically I have a data frame with lots of 'sets of positions' of items, and I want to calculate a distance matrix for each set of items. I could do this using a for loop and adding to a list, but I think there must be a more elegant method using dplyr, purrr or similar but I'm drawing a complete blank on how to proceed.

So let's assume my data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    trial = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,5),rep(3,7)),
    object_name = c("stapler", "bottle", "cup", "ball", "chocolate","tape","pen","bowl","stapler", "bottle", "cup", "ball", "tape","pen","bowl"),
    posX = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.5,-0.4,-0.1,0.8,-0.3,-0.4,0.3,0.2,0,-0.2),
    posY = c(-0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9,-0.3,-0.1,0,0.6,-0.7,-1,0.2,0.3,-0.8,0.6,1)
)
```

i.e. the object names might overlap from trial to trial, but there is a different number of objects for each trial, and my goal is to calculate a (euclidean) distance matrix using posX and posY for each trial. These matrices will be of *different size* for each trial, ranging from 3x3 to 7x7. Ideally i'd be able to store all these matrices within 1 cell of a data frame, but i'm not even so sure this is possible? If not, a list that contains for each trial a distance matrix would also work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` after you `split` *df* by *trial* what allows to calculate the distances per *trial*.

```
lapply(split(df, df$trial), function(x) dist(cbind(x$posX,x$posY)))
#lapply(split(df, df$trial), function(x) dist(cbind(x$posX,x$posY), diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)) #For a matrix
#$`1`
#          1         2
#2 0.7071068          
#3 0.5385165 0.2236068
#
#$`2`
#          1         2         3         4
#2 1.2041595                              
#3 1.0198039 0.3605551                    
#4 1.1401754 0.6708204 0.9055385          
#5 0.5000000 0.9486833 0.9219544 0.6708204
#
#$`3`
#          1         2         3         4         5         6
#2 1.1401754                                                  
#3 1.5000000 1.2041595                                        
#4 1.1180340 1.4317821 0.7071068                              
#5 0.6082763 0.5385165 1.1661904 1.1045361                    
#6 1.5264338 1.6278821 0.5656854 0.4242641 1.4142136          
#7 1.9723083 2.0024984 0.8246211 0.8602325 1.8439089 0.4472136
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 

I also found a dplyr solution for future people who come along:

```data %>% group_by(SubID, block, cluster, trial,phase) %>%
  select(posX, posZ,name.of.object) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(dist_matrix = map(data,dist))```